# variable assignment prevents from removing item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating editable area, where normal text is replaced by input and you can edit values. After editing you can hit enter or click button to accept that. During editing `edited` variable is set to true to prevent other fields to be editable. Here's the HTML

```
        <section class="person-info">
            <div class="row">
                <span id="name" class="editable">Martin Chikilian</span>
                <span id="living-place" class="editable">Portland, Oregon, USA</span>
                <span id="langs" class="editable">English, French, German</span>
            </div>
        </section>
```

and javascript code:

```
$(function(){

var edited = false;

$('.editable').click(function(){
    if(!edited){
        edited = true;
        var _this = $(this);
        var confirmIcon = (_this.attr('id') == 'name') ? 'big-confirm' : 'confirm';
        var text = $(this).text();

        //this will be injected into editable element to replace existing text
        var input = $('<input type="text" value="' + text +'" /><span id="accept" class="icon ' + confirmIcon + '"></span>');

        _this.html('');
        _this.append(input);
        input.focus();
        var accept = _this.find('#accept');

        //binding click event to confirmation button
        accept.click(function(){
                var inputVal = input.val();
                _this.html(inputVal);
                //edited = false;
        });

        //binding event to enter press
        input.keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which == 13){
                var inputVal = input.val();
                _this.html(inputVal);
                edited = false;
            }
        });
    }
});

});
```

Everything works when you hit enter, but when I try to do that by clicking acccept button it does nothing unless I remove variable assignment `edited = false;`. But it can't be left like that because it prevents other fields to be editable. What is the problem? Is it because element with event attached (accept button) is removed as well? Does anyone have any solution or clear explanation of that behavious? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you add your complete code with html?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? What happens if you move the edited=false; line to the top of that inner function?

Comment: I've tried that before, but without any success. Effect is the same. And in both cases there's no console errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `#accept` is a child of `.editable`, the `click` event that you're listening to [bubbles up the DOM](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and the click handler on `.editable` is fired off too, causing `edited === true`.

You can get around this by stopping the event from propagating using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
accept.click(function(e){
    var inputVal = input.val();

    _this.html(inputVal);
    edited = false;
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6zAN7/13/